# SQL- How to get value from a different table without joining to use on a equation?

Tags: sql, join, datatable, union

I have a table with total user count of a company by their divisions, and I have another table with total spend on multiple different products, I want to identify the per capita spend value for each product by dividing each total spend on a product by the total use count from all the divisions.

| Division | User Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 20 |
| C | 20 |
| D | 50 |
| **Total** | **100** |

Product Table,

| Product | Total Spend |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 670 |
| Orange | 580 |
| Grapes | 640 |
| Tomato | 1050 |

End result should be ,

| Product | Total Spend |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 6.7 |
| Orange | 5.8 |
| Grapes | 6.4 |
| Tomato | 10.5 |

Since there is nothing common among these tables to join, I need a way to get the total of the column of User count and use it in an equation in the query. It has to be dynamic so that even if the user count changes it will reflect on the per capita spend.

I'm using Zoho Analytics to do my online queries.

Comment: Do you really have a row with the Total in the 1st table?

Answer (score 2):

You can just aggregate before joining:

```
select p.*, p.spend * 1.0 / d.user_count
from product p cross join
     (select sum(user_count) as user_count
      from divisions
     ) d;
```